# Anyone found a way to download google chat logs?

Tags: imap, chatbot, google-data

I'd like to be able to get all my Google chat logs so that I can use them for training a chat bot type of thing.

I am aware of the limitations that have been imposed by Google so that chats cannot be simply downloaded through IMAP.  I'm looking for workarounds.

Comment: This isn't really programming related.

Comment: i need to write a program that will access google mail and download data to be fed into another program.  i'm not sure why this wouldn't be considered programming related.

Comment: Just wondering: Have you done any work on this?

Answer (score 7):

As of September 2011, Google removed the restriction on downloading chats. Google **[now allows](http://dataliberation.blogspot.com/2011/09/gmail-liberates-recorded-chat-logs-via.html)** export of chatlogs using IMAP.

Comment: I wrote a quick python script that downloads all of your chat transcripts using IMAP and saves them into a directory on your filesystem. https://github.com/paykroyd/chats

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to download the chat logs unless they're attached to an email conversation - maybe you could fwd all of the logs that are held in your 'chats' folder and then download the conversations over IMAP or POP?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to do the same thing and coded a quick ruby script. http://9seats.com/2011/04/archiving-gmail-chat-logs-with-ruby/

Comment: Hi @J.R. , The link is not working. Can you please share the ruby script

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to make a program to do this, you **could** use a greasemonkey script and a local PHP server.
The greasemonkey script would pick up chats as you visit them, parse them, and send them to the local PHP server, which could then dump it to a TXT, SQL, whatever.
Contact me if you want some help, I might be interested in this, though I'll be on holidays the next months :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a wander through the [Google Talk API](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html). And this may, or may not, help too: [GMailAPI](http://www.johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to download a email. You can do the same to chat. Because chats are nothing but an email tagged with label chat. If you see chats, they are actually sent from the person you chatted with to you.

Comment: Sorry, but they are not in the proper RFC 822(Please correct me if I'm wrong) format.